# how to find number of presentation of 1 as a sum of $2^{-i}$?

Tags: combinatorics, egyptian-fractions

How to find number of presentations of 1 as a sum of exactly $k$ numbers of the form $2^{-i}$ ?
As an example for $k=2$ we have only one presentation:
$$1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2},$$
so answer for $k = 2$ is 1.  For $k=4$,
$$1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}$$
and
$$1 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4},$$
so the answer is 2.

How to find the formula for all $k$?

Comment: So you me sum of **powers o**f $2^{-1}?$

Comment: sorry, yes i mean sum

Comment: Hint I haven't tried. There's a recursion lurking here since with $k$ terms you can expand one of them to find an expression with $k+1$ terms. Sometimes the expansions will match, which you have to account for,

Comment: Generating function, but it doesn't seem to get us anywhere. Consider:

$$f_m(w,z)=\prod_{j=0}^{m}\frac1{1-wz^{2^{j}}}$$

Then you want to find the coefficient of $w^kz^{2^m}$ for $m=\lfloor \log_2 k\rfloor.$ But I don't immediately see how to do that.

Comment: That wasn't my question. Reread my first comment. $1=\frac12+\frac12$ is the only way to write $1$ as the sum of $2^{-1}.$ $2^{-2}$ is not $2^{-1}.$ @rrryok

Comment: But ... @rrryok ... How is $1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}$ a sum of $2^{-1}$'s?

Comment: You actually can use the infinite product of my formula for the general formula. Interesting, in the infinite product, the sequence of coefficients of $w^kz^{2^m}$ becomes constant for $m$ large, and that constant is the value you want. In particular, we can always choose $m=k.$

Comment: This is https://oeis.org/A002572

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, @
Stinking Bishop, sorry, my bad, there is $2^{-i}$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews sorry, i don't get what it's w and z in your formula,  can you give an example in usage

Comment: This came up again today: [Find a formula for this sequence: 1,1,1,2,3,5,9,16,28,50,89...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4666959/25554)

Comment: @mick No, $m\neq w.$ I was giving a generating function, which, if you don't know generating functions, probably isn't going to be of much use to you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh sorry i thought the product went to infinity and was not seeing the m. apologies

Comment: Think binary is the easiest.